# unable to set path of Boost_LIBRARIES other than default

Tags: visual-studio-2010, boost, cmake

I have compiled boost library in stage/Win32/ folder. 
When I do

```
target_link_libraries(${TARGET} ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
```

I get path to stage/lib/*libname* locations 
which won't work in visual studio.

how do I get path of library as stage/win32/*libname*

Answer (score 0):

There is a hint variable `Boost_LIBRARY_DIR` that you can set that will tell the find module where to look for the libraries.

```
cmake -DBoost_LIBRARY_DIR:PATH=D:/boost/stage/win32/ ..
```

You'll probably have to clear the cmake cache before re-running cmake.